# Visual Studio 2015 How to make the WebBrowser control unclickable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to make a simple app for me and my friend. The app is used for his radio station. I currently have a basic WebBrowser control. The WebBrowser control is locked at a certain location on twitter, so that you can see all the tweets his radio station tweets out.

It looks good and works fine. The last thing I need to do is to make the WebBrowser control unclickable, whilst you can still scroll through the internet page. This means that I don't want people to be able to press on a tweet in the list. I tried putting a transparent panel of the browser, this just creates a hole in the browser and shows the background.

Does anyone have an idea how to make the WebBrowser control unclickable?

Comment: Did you try disabling it? Just set its `Enabled` property to false

Comment: Set to `false` all properties ending with `*Enabled`.

Comment: Just hook into click event and return false?

Comment: Can't make a click event, in the properties it doesn't have a click event like the other controls do.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to stop the browser from navigating anywhere:

```
wb.Navigating += (s, e) => e.Cancel = true;
```

But I honestly don't know if that will also work for any fancy AJAX techniques.

If you want to enable some navigation you can also check for the `e.Uri` or possibly allow the navigation if `e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Refresh`.

Comment: Tried the piece of code you sent me, I get an error dropped. The error:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter OoutputRadio3.0 C:\Users\Thowmas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OoutputRadio3.0\OoutputRadio3.0\Form1.cs 326 A‌​ctive –  Didn't know you can't press enter for a new line of text, so sorry for the three comments. I have another problem when using that code. Pressing a tweet makes a window pop up, so it isn't really navigating is it?

Comment: @Thow Just give `e` another name that isn't already in use. For example `wb.Navigating += (s, ea) => ea.Cancel = true;`. Unfortunately preventing a new window from opening is a bit harder. [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx) you can find a sample of a possible solution where you manually process every `OnWebBrowserNewWindow` request and stop it from happening. (Just make sure to leave out the `MyWebBrowser.Navigate(URL);`.)

Comment: Thanks Haindl I'll take a look in just a second. Ill message you back when I tried your suggestion.

Comment: @Thow You're welcome. Just ask if something is unclear.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It doesn't work tho. I don't have any errors, and the applications runs fine. Do you know a different way to prevent people from interacting with the webbrowser?

Comment: @Thow What doesn't work? The cancelling of the navigation or the prevention of opening a new window? Do you have a public URL for me where it doesn't work? (And please specify the link or the action on that page if you do.)

Comment: I don't even know what doesn't work. I use the link http://twitter.com/outputradio and I want to prevent that you can press a tweet or anything else. I don't see any effect with the code from the site you sent me.

Comment: @Thow [Here](http://pastebin.com/4SB3mnDH) is the absolute minimum amount of code that is necessary in WinForms and [here](http://pastebin.com/XiwWYeYn) in WPF (which is a bit more complicated). It works pretty fine for me as it blocks navigation to other sites and the opening of new windows. As I assumed, it doesn't work for AJAX-like navigation inside the same page - for example when you click on the top left Twitter icon. I really don't know if that kind of JavaScript navigation can successfully be prevented. But aside from that it should do the job. Please check if that code works for you.

Comment: Aha, I see! It blocks some parts like you said it would. But unfortunately not the popups when you press a tweet. But it's a step in the right direction! Thanks for the help Haindl.

Comment: @Thow Glad I could help! :-) I hope you find a way to block the unwanted popups but I think that this will only work if you parse the HTML and block that behavior directly by manipulating the DOM. (Of course this will be extremly customized and will only work for this single site.) If my answer was nonetheless somewhat useful to you, I would be happy if you would mark it as the accepted answer. (And upvote if you didn't already.)

Comment: I would vote this comment up if I could, I just don't have the amount of points to. Don't get me wrong but if I mark it as an answer people start skipping this question and maybe there's somebody who has an even better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that would work but try creating click event and place only 'return;' instruction in the event code. that should cancel the click.

Comment: The problem is that I unfortunately can't create a click event

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter OoutputRadio3.0 C:\Users\Thowmas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OoutputRadio3.0\OoutputRadio3.0\Form1.cs 326 Active

Comment: Didn't know you can't press enter for a new line of text, so sorry for the three comments. I have another problem when using that code. Pressing a tweet makes a window pop up, so it isn't really navigating is it? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Ignore the last 2 comments, my web browser is acting funny. Meant to place it at a different answer.